# Alexa: Unable to change a pluralize word to singular

Tags: javascript, node.js, alexa-skills-kit

Trying to change the word attempts to attempt on an Alexa quiz skill.  Currently if you get the answer right , it will say  you have guessed it right in 1 attempts. I want it to say you have guessed it right in 1 attempt.

```
function pluralize(count, singular, plural) {
  if(count === 1) {
    return `${count} ${singular}`;
  } else {
    return `${count} ${plural}`;
  }
}
```

added the function to this line in the AnswerIntent

```
var speech = "<audio src='https://s3.amazonaws.com/ask-soundlibrary/ui/gameshow/amzn_ui_sfx_gameshow_tally_positive_01.mp3'/>Well done, you have guessed it right in " + (4-count) + " ${pluralize(count, `attempt`, `attempts`)}. Your score is " + score + " . Do you wish to play again? say Yes to play again and No to quit.";
```

but the result is

Well done, you have guessed it right in 3 . Your score is 8 . Do you wish to play again? say Yes to play again and No to quit.

full code of AnswerIntent

```
"AnswerIntent" : function(){
        var guess = this.event.request.intent.slots.Guess.value;
        var l1 = this.event.request.intent.slots.LetterOne.value;
        var l2 = this.event.request.intent.slots.LetterTwo.value;
        var l3 = this.event.request.intent.slots.LetterThree.value;
        var l4 = this.event.request.intent.slots.LetterFour.value;
        var index = this.attributes.Game.index;
        var count = this.attributes.Game.count;
        var answer = arr[index].A;
        var a = answer.split('');
        if(guess !== undefined && l1 !== undefined && l2 !== undefined && l3 !== undefined && l4 !== undefined){
            l1 = l1.toLowerCase();
            l2 = l2.toLowerCase();
            l3 = l3.toLowerCase();
            l4 = l4.toLowerCase();
            if(guess === answer && (l1 === a[0] || l1 === a[0] + ".") && (l2 === a[1] || l2 === a[1] + ".") && (l3 === a[2] || l3 === a[2] + ".") && (l4 === a[3] || l4 === a[3] + ".") ){
                this.attributes.Game.score += 1;
                var score = this.attributes.Game.score;
                **var speech = "<audio src='https://s3.amazonaws.com/ask-soundlibrary/ui/gameshow/amzn_ui_sfx_gameshow_tally_positive_01.mp3'/>Well done, you have guessed it right in " + (4-count) + " ${pluralize(count, `attempt`, `attempts`)}. Your score is " + score + " . Do you wish to play again? say Yes to play again and No to quit.";**

                this.emit(":askWithCard",speech,speech, "Well done", "your Score is " + score + ". To play again say, YES or to quit say, NO");
            }else{
                this.attributes.Game.count -= 1;
                count = this.attributes.Game.count;
                var question = arr[index].Q;
                var q = "<break time='0.5s'/>" + question.split('').join("<break time='0.5s'/>") + "<break time='0.5s'/>";
                if(count > 0){
                    var speech1 = "<audio src='https://s3.amazonaws.com/ask-soundlibrary/ui/gameshow/amzn_ui_sfx_gameshow_tally_negative_01.mp3'/> Please try again, your jumbled letters were " + q + ". You have " + count + " ${pluralize(attempts, `attempt`, `attempts`)}";
                    this.emit(":askWithCard",speech1,speech1,"Attempts Left: " + count, " Try again, your guess " + l1 + " "+ l2 + " "+l3 + " "+ l4 + " " + guess + " is incorrect");
                }else{
                    var ans = "<break time='0.5s'/>" + answer.split('').join("<break time='0.5s'/>") + "<break time='0.5s'/>";
                    var speech2 = "<audio src='https://s3.amazonaws.com/ask-soundlibrary/ui/gameshow/amzn_ui_sfx_gameshow_tally_negative_01.mp3'/> Sorry, there are no attempts left, the correct animal is " + ans + answer + ". Do you wish to play again? say Yes to play again and No to quit";
                    this.emit(":askWithCard",speech2,speech2,"NO MORE ATTEMPTS LEFT", "The correct animal is " + answer);
                }
            }
        }else{
            this.emit(":askWithCard","Please guess by spelling out the animal","Please guess by spelling out the animal","Please Spell the Animal","The guess should have the letters spelled out in the right order, followed by the name of the animal after that");
        }
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

Template literals has to be inside backticks. In your line of code, you're mixing backticks with double quotes and that might be the problem. Try this:

```
var speech = `<audio src='https://s3.amazonaws.com/ask-soundlibrary/ui/gameshow/amzn_ui_sfx_gameshow_tally_positive_01.mp3'/>Well done, you have guessed it right in ${pluralize(count, 'attempt', 'attempts')}. Your score is ${score} Do you wish to play again? say Yes to play again and No to quit.`
```